# How to serve fewer images to mobile sites

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a website where the homepage is a `div` with six `divs` and six `imgs` in it.  I want to know the best way to make it so that on a mobile site only one `div` / `img` is served.  I know there are a lot of tricks to re-organize the page using CSS, but I do not want the `imgs` hidden, I want them not created (on mobile devices) at all. I would like this without jQuery.  Is this even possible?

**HTML (Full Size)**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>
</div>
```

**Ideal HTML (Mobile Size)**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" alt="Example" src="example.png"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you seem to be indicating that you want the solution to be on the server, not the client. however, you don't mention your hosting platform.

Comment: The only way to do what you are asking is via the server side. The server will have to look at the `User Agent` in the header and determine if the device is a Mobile or Desktop device and then serve up the correct page based on that. If you want to do it client side just hide the images you do not want in a `@media-query` but it sounds like you don't want to do that.

Comment: Server side. Here's one idea: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: You can put the links to your images from `src=` in a `data-*` html element and then when you want to serve the image you can take the link to the image and put it into and <img> tag and display it to the user. So if you are on Mobile only grab the first one with your Javascript if you are on Desktop grab them all.

Comment: @jimmyjimmy : that rocks

Comment: @NoahHuppert - Unfortunately, hiding an image will not prevent the browser from loading it.

Comment: @jimmyjimmy I like this solution, however, it would also mean using javascript to create the `divs` as well, correct?

Comment: @Startec It depends on what you want to happen when javascript is disabled. When javascript is enabled you should be able to achieve the same visual effects either way.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I am aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side instead of putting the links to the images in the `src=` part of the `<img>` tag you can put them into a `data-*` tag and then after you establish whether your site is being browsed on desktop or mobile browser you can write javscript to take the corresponding image link(s) out of the `data-*` and put them into their `src=` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should **detect if the browser is a mobile browser**, and then behave properly.

First of all, remove the elements in your mainContainer and put them inside some JavaScript variables, so your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
</div>
```

And your Javascript like this:

```
var desktopElements = '<div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>' 
    +'<div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>'
    + ... ;
var mobileElements = '<div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"><img class="staging" ald="a picture" src="example.png"></div></div>';
```

In the `desktopElements` variable you put all the divs, in the `mobileElements` variable you only put one div.

Then inside your code you will detect if the browser is mobile and then load the elements:

```
var isMobile = 'ontouchstart' in window,
    container = document.getElementById('mainContainer');

if (isMobile) container.innerHTML = mobileElements;
else container.innerHTML = desktopElements;
```

Comment: What is this is on a touchscreen device that is a full computer? Wouldn't detecting `ontouchstart` mislead the page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it on the client side without using JavaScript.

Browsers load even hidden elements. They will load images even if you set them as background property on hidden elements.

The only solution is to generate a different HTML for mobile devices (if you use PHP, JSP, etc.), or use JavaScript to remove unnecessary image elements before a page is rendered.

Comment: Thought so, this sounds like the sad truth to me.